# Microsoft Access limiting days to middle of a month

Tags: database, ms-access, ms-access-2007, ms-access-2010

I'm trying to apply a constraint to my BeginDate and EndDate so it satisfied this requirement:

Time periods are defined by a beginning and an end date, and are usually from the first of a month to the middle of the month, or from the middle of a month to the end of the month.

My problem is I don't know how to limit days to middle of the month. MS Access doesn't have "if". Can you help me please.

Comment: re: "Access doesn't have 'if'" - I guess you are not aware of the [IIf() function](https://support.office.microsoft.com/en-ca/article/IIf-Function-32436ecf-c629-48a3-9900-647539c764e3?CorrelationId=ed6cabe8-0d96-4d0a-897a-46e3fb24541a&ui=en-US&rs=en-CA&ad=CA).

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? Set a hard constraint to the table's field that those days cannot be entered? Or just set front end restriction for users?

Comment: I would not even suggest the option of back end limiting. All validation, entry should be performed by and through Forms. Direct addition to tables should be avoided to make sure data integrity is followed. @Hirad, please explain what sort of scenario you are dealing with to give you a correct solution.